# send data between AJAX and php

Tags: php, ajax, joomla

I have this AJAX

```
   function  getValFromDb() {
   var university = document.getElementById('category').value;
   var domain = document.getElementById('subcategory').value;
   var year = document.getElementById('an').value;
   var url = "modules/mod_data/tmpl/script.php";

  var params = 'uni='+university+'&fac='+domain+'&an='+year;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { AJAX=new XMLHttpRequest(); } else { AJAX=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
    if (AJAX)
    {
        AJAX.open("POST", url, false);
        AJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        AJAX.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(AJAX.readyState == 4 && AJAX.status == 200)
            {
             document.getElementById('materie').innerHTML = AJAX.responseText;
            }
        }; 

    } AJAX.send(params);
    }
```

an send params here

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$an=$_POST('an');
$fac=$_POST('fac');
$uni=$_POST('uni');
  $result1 =mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT (materie) FROM drv_uni_$uni WHERE an='$an'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    $display_string .= "<option value=\"".$row['id']."\">". $row['materie'] ."</option>";
} 

  echo $display_string;
?>
```

POST from firebug

```
      Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
      an    an-3
      fac   Finante Banci
      uni   ase
      Source
      uni=ase&fac=Finante Banci&an=an-3
```

And HEADERS

```
     Response Headers

        Connection  keep-alive
      Content-Encoding  gzip
       Content-Type text/html
       Date Sun, 30 Dec 2012 13:12:47 GMT
      Server    xServers
      Transfer-Encoding chunked
       X-Powered-By PHP/5.3.16
```

Request Headers

```
       Accept   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
      Accept-Encoding   gzip, deflate
      Accept-Language   en-US,en;q=0.5
        Connection  keep-alive
     Content-Length 33
        Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
       Cookie   0dea1a59adf779fae552e16f3d646b24=91481693c6b3c8615aa9ce57461aa590; 33a66e84ea7ae1332853383606d933e1=2039ee6737b4252207431790f5f7a939
              DNT   1
        Host    www.domain.ro
       Referer  http://www.domain.ro/upload
       User-Agent   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0
```

THE RESPONSE IS EMPTY!

the Js doesn.t receive anything from php. The PHP have take the values corectly but when it send it doesnt get back to js. If you wanna show me how to use JSON or to corect this code i apreciate.

Comment: Perhaps the MySQL query returns nothing, so your loop won't run and $display_string remains empty. What happens if you do `echo "Display string should appear here: " . $display_string;` instead of just `echo $display_string;`

Comment: And are you sure it didn't die on `defined("_JEXEC") or die;`? Check this by changing that to: `defined("_JEXEC") or die("DEAD");`. That should echo 'DEAD' if it dies.

Comment: The PHP is doing his job as i say. I debugged there.

Comment: if  i echo "Display string should appear here: " . $display_string still nothing displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `defined('_JEXEC') or die;` to `define('_JEXEC', 1) or die;`. Note I have used **define** instead of **defined**. This has been an issue for a lot of people integrating Ajax in their extension as `defined('_JEXEC') or die;` usually blocks it for security reasons.

Comment: @ValValli - Glad it works :) Please accept the answer by click the "tick" icon on the left to show it has been solved.

Comment: Remember that removing this is a security issue though. It allows another entry point into Joomla!

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the above scenario as follow.

1. Check whether your PHP page is being hit by the AJAX query. To do that echo "something" and see the That shows on the firebug response tab. `defined('_JEXEC') or die;` might be stopping the script and etc.
2. Make sure AJAX URL is correct and POST data are passed correctly to the PHP side.
3. Check whether your MYSQL query is correct and it returns the data you want.
4. Make sure you retrive the response from the PHP side and shows it in the AJAX success function.
5. Watch out JS error during the process. To make sure you have no errors you can use firebug.

Comment: JS doesn.t return errors MYSQL is Correct. i dont understand what you mean by AJAx url is correct.

Comment: Why don't you make the ajax call using jQuery. It's easier

Comment: if you are not familiar It's useless to be used because you won't be able to make modifications afterwards even we get the AJAX set up right.